# Regex for starting with and not ends

Tags: php, regex

I want to check a string if it starts with dollar (`$`) and open brace (`{`) followed by anything but not ends with closing brace (`}`).

```
{$this should match {$this shouldn't march}
```

I tried following:

```
$regex = '/(^\{\$).*?(?!\\})$/';
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: Which format do you want match, exactly? `${...` or `{$...`? Please clarify. (Also, edit the title of your question.)

Comment: {$.. but not ends with }

Comment: Do you want to just match? Or do you want to extract the `{$this should match ` from it?

Comment: And what's wrong with your attempt? You could show some sample strings that must match and some that mustn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am hazarding a guess that your example was intended to be two separate examples, one of which should match and one of which should not match. The following `regex` may do what you want.

```
<?php
$input1 =    '{$this should match' ;
$input2 = '{$this shouldn\'t march}';
$regex = '/^{\$[^{}]+(?!})$/';

preg_match_all($regex, $input1, $matches); // Will match
var_dump($matches);
preg_match_all($regex, $input2, $matches); // Will not match
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. I just want to know why to use [^{}] in your regex /^{\$[^{}]+(?!})$/    ?

Comment: @pavankumar, I am using `[^{}]` because I am trying to match any character that is not `{` or `}`. That seemed to be what you implied in your question, but if you do not mind additional `{`, then you can change it to `[^}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not completely clear. OK, it is not clear at all.

```
$regex = '/(^\{\$).*?(?!\\})$/';
                         |
                     double escaping, why?
```

A [lookaround assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is checking a condition at a certain position in the pattern. `(?!\})$` checks if at a position `(?!\})` is true **and** `$` is true.

**These two conditions will be always true at the end of the string!** ==> you are not checking if the string does not end with a `}`:

The [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `$` is true, if the end of the string is ahead, at the same position `(?!\})` is also true, because there is no `}` ahead.

To test this condition, **you have to look back**, when `$` is found ==>

```
(?<!\})$
```